# Android in-app purchase error: Your order could not be processed

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I'm having a problem with getting the in-app purchasing to work. When implementing the in-app purchases I followed the steps on the Google Developer website found here:
https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html

The app is released in the Google Play Store and i'm trying to buy in-app purchases with a different account than my Google Developer account (I tried several other). The latest release of my app was done on 18th of Januari.

So about the code, everything seems to be allright and the purchaseflow is launched through this code. the reference in the buyConsumable method is the SKU.

```
public void buyConsumable(String reference, BuyConsumableCompletionHandler handler) {
    this.reference = reference;
    defaultHandler = handler;

    if(iabHelper != null) {
        try {
            iabHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(activity, reference, 10001, this);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(Constants.ERROR, e.getLocalizedMessage());
            defaultHandler.purchaseFailed();
        }
    } else {
        defaultHandler.purchaseFailed();
    }
}
```

I'm using the default iabHelper nothing fancy. When the launchflow is called and the Google Play Store popup appears I see the following Exception in my Android Monitor:

> 01-24 14:29:53.891 4865-5272/? E/Parcel: Class not found when unmarshalling: com.google.android.finsky.billing.lightpurchase.PurchaseParams
>                                            java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.finsky.billing.lightpurchase.PurchaseParams
>                                                at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
>                                                at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:324)
>                                                at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2404)
>                                                at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2358)
>                                                at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2264)
>                                                at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2614)
>                                                at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:221)
>                                                at android.os.BaseBundle.getString(BaseBundle.java:920)
>                                                at android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(Intent.java:6195)
>                                                at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:2699)
>                                                at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startActivityMayWait(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:2161)
>                                                at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityInPackage(ActivityManagerService.java:6877)
>                                                at com.android.server.am.PendingIntentRecord.sendInner(PendingIntentRecord.java:310)
>                                                at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityIntentSender(ActivityManagerService.java:6635)
>                                                at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:292)
>                                                at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:3991)
>                                                at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:453)
>                                             Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.finsky.billing.lightpurchase.PurchaseParams
>                                                at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
>                                                at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
>                                                at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
>                                                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
>                                                at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 
>                                                at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:324) 
>                                                at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2404) 
>                                                at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2358) 
>                                                at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2264) 
>                                                at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2614) 
>                                                at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:221) 
>                                                at android.os.BaseBundle.getString(BaseBundle.java:920) 
>                                                at android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(Intent.java:6195) 
>                                                at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:2699) 
>                                                at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startActivityMayWait(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:2161) 
>                                                at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityInPackage(ActivityManagerService.java:6877) 
>                                                at com.android.server.am.PendingIntentRecord.sendInner(PendingIntentRecord.java:310) 
>                                                at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityIntentSender(ActivityManagerService.java:6635) 
>                                                at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:292) 
>                                                at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:3991) 
>                                                at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:453) 
>                                             Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available

I can still go through with the purchase, so i'm pressing the buy button and then use my Paypal / CC to buy the in app purchase. I'm getting the following error in the Android Monitor:

> E/Volley: [4116] c.a: Unexpected response code 500 for https://android.clients.google.com/fdfe/ees/commitPurchase

And the following Error pops up on my screen:
[image: Error image]

I've checked the license code which you get from the Google Developer console when clicking on the app and navigating to Services and API's and that code is also the same as the code i'm using in the app.

Anybody got an idea on how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

After numerous emails to Google Support and finally able to find the livechat function. The Google support dude told me that my Google Wallet account was disabled. The issue is now emailed to the Google Buyers Payment Support team for further investigation and fixing. They'll be in contact via email with me about this issue.